# How to Decompress a TAR file into TXT (read a CEL file) in either Python or R

Tags: python, r, windows, tar, data-conversion

I was wondering if anyone knows how to decompress TAR files in R and how to extrapolate data from large numbers of GZ files? In addition, does anyone know how to read large amounts of data (around the 100's) simultaneously while maintaining the integrity of the data files (at some point, my computer can't handle the amount of data and begins to write down scribbles)?

As a novice programmer still learning about programming. I was given an assignment to analyze and cross-reference data on similar genes found between different cell structures for a disease trait. I managed to access TXT dataset files to work and formatted it to be recognized by another program known as GSEA.

1.) I installed a software known as "WinZip" and it helped me decompress my TAR files into GZ files.
I stored these files into an newly created folder under "Downloads"

2.) I then tried to use R to access the files with this code:

```
   >untar("file.tar", list=TRUE)

And it produced approximately 170 results (it converted TAR -> GZ files)
```

3.) When I tried to input one of the GZ files, it generated over a thousand lines of single alpha-numerical letters and numbers unintelligible to me.

```
                >989                                               ™šBx
                >990                                   33BŸ™šC:LÍC\005€
                >991                                               LÍB¬
                >992                                     B«™šBê™šB™™šB¯
                >993                                                 B¡
                >994                                                 BŸ
                >995                                              C\003
                >996                                         BŽ™šBð™šB¦
                >997                                                 B(
                >998                                           LÍAòffBó
                >999                                           LÍBñ™šBó
                >1000                                                 €

      > [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 64340 rows ]
         Warning messages:
      >1: In read.table("GSM2458563_Control_1_0.CEL.gz") :
       line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
      >2: In read.table("GSM2458563_Control_1_0.CEL.gz") :
       line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
      >3: In read.table("GSM2458563_Control_1_0.CEL.gz") :
       line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
      >4: In read.table("GSM2458563_Control_1_0.CEL.gz") :
       line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
      >5: In read.table("GSM2458563_Control_1_0.CEL.gz") :
       line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
      >6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
       embedded nul(s) found in input
```

What I am trying to do is simultaneously access all of these files without information overload on the computer and maintain the integrity of the data. Then, I want to access the information properly where it would resemble some sort of data table (ideally, I was wondering if conversions from TAR to TXT file would have been possible for GSEA to read and identify such data).

Does anyone know any programs compatible with window that could properly decompress and read such files or any R commands that would help me generate or convert such data files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Backgound Research***

So I've been working on it around an hour - here are the results.

The file that you are trying to open is `GSM2458563_Control_1_0` is compressed inside `.gz` file, which contains a `.CELL` file, therefore it's unreadable.

Such files are published by the ["National Center for Biotechnology Information"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/).

Seen a Python 2 code to open them:

```
from Bio.Affy import CelFile
with open('GSM2458563_Control_1_0.CEL') as file: 
    c = CelFile.read(file)
```

I've found documentation about [Bio.Affy](https://biopython.org/docs/1.74/api/Bio.Affy.CelFile.html) on version 1.74 of biopython.

Yet current [biopython readme](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/README.rst) says:

> "...Biopython 1.76 was our final release to support Python 2.7 and Python 3.5."

Nowadays Python 2 is deprecated, not to mention that the [library](https://biopython.org/) mentioned above has evolved and changed tremendously.

***Solution***

So I found another way around it, using R.

My Specs:

```
Operation System : Windows 64
RStudio          : Version 1.3.1073
R Version        : R-4.0.2 for Windows
```

I've pre-installed the dependencies mentioned below.

Use the [`GEOquery.getGEO`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GEOquery/versions/2.38.4/topics/getGEO) function to fetch from [NCBI GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo) the file.

```
# Presequites
# Download and install Rtools custom from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

# Install BiocManager
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly=TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GEOquery")


library(GEOquery)

# Download and open the data
gse <- getGEO("GSM2458563", GSEMatrix = TRUE)
show(gse)

# ****** Data Table ******
#    ID_REF    VALUE
# 1 7892501 1.267832
# 2 7892502 3.254963
# 3 7892503 1.640587
# 4 7892504 7.198422
# 5 7892505 2.226013
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your dedication, time and effort to find a solution to my dilemma! You are indeed MVP. I have tried asking this question with most of my mentors and they just responded with unzip and read one at a time or LINUX.  I have tried your method on R and it actually works!!! I can't thank you enough for how much help you have provided me.

Comment: Welcome @StephenSitu ! All luck :)